# cURL shows information that I don't wanna see

Tags: curl

today I was trying to add some wttr.in commands with curl to my powershell terminal profile. But when I just run the "curl wttr.in/Kayseri?format=3" it shows these informations that I don't wanna see because it's too much.

`StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : London: ⛅️  +11°C

RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 23....`

What can I do about that? How can I just get the weather output?

Answer (score 0):

Using the silent switch should help.

`curl -s https://foo.tld`